# SQL Server: Retrieve last error on INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to get the latest `INSERT` error in SQL Server ? I've a program that fails at the `INSERT` but don't give explanations/log information about the error. I tried to watch the Windows Registry of server; but nothing on `INSERT` statement fails.

Comment: under which path u checked the log information?

Comment: SQL Profiler may help you ;).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to get the value of @@ERROR:

```
DECLARE @res int
INSERT ....
SET @res = @@ERROR
SELECT @res
```

Comment: @skini82 Was the solution useful?